# Keras function parameters not valid Python?

Tags: python, function, keras

I am working through a course on deep learning with Python and ran into this line:

`hidden = Dense(2)(visible)`

What does the second parameter do? Is this a python language feature I've missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember asking the same thing when I was learning Keras.

```
hidden = Dense(2)(visible)
```

You can rewrite this in a more verbose way as below:

```
dense_layer = Dense(2)
hidden = dense_layer(visible)
```

As you can see from the above, the first line creates an instance of the `Dense` layer, and then you can call that layer on a tensor. This adds the `Dense` operation to a graph of operations.

Comment: Ah. I was wondering if it returned a function. Thank you.

Comment: It does __not__ return a function. It creates a class, and that class implements the `__call__` method, which allows you to call it like a function. Also if this answered your question, please accept it by clicking the green check mark.

Answer (score 0):

`Visible` is not a language specific feature or something. Your code should not have only this line but before that you probably define a variable named `visible` like below.

```
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import Dense
visible = Input(shape=(2,))
hidden = Dense(2)(visible)
```

Here are some examples:

[source1](https://jovianlin.io/keras-models-sequential-vs-functional/)
[source2](https://machinelearningmastery.com/keras-functional-api-deep-learning/)